# $\sum \frac{n^2+1}{n+2}$ using root test

Tags: calculus, summation

If I'm only using root test, then is $\sum \frac{n^2+1}{n+2}$ useful to root test? I make it $(\frac{n^2+1}{n+2})^{\frac{1}{n}}$ simply, and it's turning to 1. Then there is impossible to see if the test works. ¿Yes? or no.

Comment: What is the limit of the general term?

Comment: The Root Test is not useful for series with general terms which are rational functions of polynomials; it is best suited for general terms involving functions raised to powers where the exponents are functions of $ \ n \ $ , such as $ \ n \ ,  \ 3n \ , \ n^2 \ , $ and the like.  Simpler such exponents are better to deal with, since you still need to be able to find the limit at infinity of the $ \ n-$ th-root you've formed.

Comment: @BernardMassé The limit is turning to 1. I said that in the question

Comment: I asked you what the limit of $\frac{n^2+1}{n+2}$ (the general term) was. This is what Actually Fritz did and you accepted his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the value of the limit in this particular case, the root test is inconclusive. However, note that $\frac{n^2 + 1}{n + 2} \geq 1$ for all $n \geq 2,$ so that your series does not converge. Another way to see this is to note that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2 + 1}{n + 2} = \infty.$ I hope this helps. :)